# chart js label callback is asking for type declaration

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

so i'm currently reconstructing a platform from old angular to a newer one, plus  a rule is that everything must have it´s type declaration and so i found myself in this problem where the label callback is showing this error

Type '(tooltipItem: any, data: any) => string' is not assignable to type '(this: TooltipModel<"pie">, tooltipItem: TooltipItem<"pie">) => string | string[]'.

here is the code:
callbacks:{
label: function (tooltipItem:any, data:any){
return data['labels'][tooltipItem['index']] + ': ' + data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']] + '%';
}
}

im trying to add the % to the tooltip labels and it works on the old platform but here i don´t now how to solve this error

here is the index of chart js making reference to the label callback
label(this: Model, tooltipItem: Item): string | string[];

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js has build in typings so the callbacks already are typed so you don't need to provide your own typings.

If you really want to type it yourself you need to copy paste the typings from.chart.js you get in your error and use those

Comment: it is not that i want to type it myself, im literally getting a vs-code error asking me to type it as i said here "Type '(tooltipItem: any, data: any) => string' is not assignable to type '(this: TooltipModel<"pie">, tooltipItem: TooltipItem<"pie">) => string | string[]'." but copying and pasting the types in my error does not work